# Setting the default values in a SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

how to set default values from my sqlite database in android studio

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, indo TEXT, tdr TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (indo,tdr) VALUES (ikan,nyao)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I want to enter sample data in my database, then when I try to run an error in

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (indo,tdr) VALUES (ikan,nyao)");
```

where's the mistake, huh? Is it because of the rules of writing?

Comment: Enclose the values in quotes: `INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (indo,tdr) VALUES ('ikan','nyao')`

Comment: @forpas **Thank u sir.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the values need to be enclosed in single quotes, otherwise they are considered as entity names (column names in this case).

so you could use :-

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (indo,tdr) VALUES ('ikan','nyao')") //<<<<<<<<<< ikan and nyao enclosed in single quotes
```

However, the  *more correct* way would be to use bound parameters in which case you could use :

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE+" (indo,tdr) VALUES (?,?)",new String[]{"ikan","nyao"});
```

- when binding the parameters (replacing the **`?`**'s with the respective values) the values are enclosed offering protection against SQL injection (albeit that an SQL injection attack is not possible as the data is not user supplied).